# Jest Mocking a function implementation on a global level

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I've got a utility function that looks like this:

```
const getTimezoneString = (): string => {
  return Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
};
```

Since this function is part of an app that would run on multiple new/old browsers, I wanted to test the `Intl` support for different platforms.

I'm looking for a way to globally define a mock implementation of the `Intl` object so that when I do something like:

```
expect(getTimezoneString()).toEquall("Africa/Nirobi")
```

similarly, I would change the timeZone in the implementation and test if my function returns the new timezone.

I would also like to test, what happens if the Intl object is not supported by the browser. i.e returning undefined or throwing an error probably.

I've been using jest mockImplementation method to create a mock that returns the desired output:

```
const IntlDateTimeFormatMock = jest
      .fn(Intl.DateTimeFormat)
      .mockImplementation(() => undefined);
```

Is there a way I can get this mock function to automatically replace the output of the Intl whenever I call my utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone going through the same problem, this is how I ended up doing it:

```
describe('My Utility - getTimezoneString', () => {
  const originalIntl = Intl;

  beforeEach(() => {
    global.Intl = originalIntl;
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    global.Intl = originalIntl;
  });

  it('should return Africa/Nirobi', () => {
    global.Intl = {
      DateTimeFormat: () => ({
        resolvedOptions: jest
          .fn()
          .mockImplementation(() => ({ timeZone: 'Africa/Nirobi' })),
      }),
    } as any;

    expect(getTimezoneString()).toEqual('Africa/Nirobi');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest changing only the desired method of `DateTimeFormat` class due to possible others methods usage within an application. You can do it like so:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  const originalDateResolvedOptions = new Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions();
  jest.spyOn(Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype, 'resolvedOptions').mockReturnValue({
    ...originalDateResolvedOptions,
    timeZone: 'America/Godthab',
  });
});
```

This overwrites only the returned `timeZone` property (we may of course want to overwrite more, depending on our needs)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to mock the `Intl` class (and its methods) globally, something like:

```
const _global = typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : window;

beforeAll(() => {
  _global.Intl = jest.fn(() =>
    DateTimeFormat: () => ({ resolvedOptions: () => ({ timezone: 'Africa/Nirobi' }) }));
});

afterAll(() => {
  Intl.mockClear();
});

test('it returns correct timezone string', () => {
  expect(getTimezoneString()).toEqual('Africa/Nirobi')
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Just trying what you suggested but I get undefined when calling `Intl.DateTimeFormat` after mocking it in the beforeAll.

```
  beforeAll(() => {
    // @ts-ignore
    _global.Intl = jest.fn(() => {
      return {
        DateTimeFormat: () => ({
          resolvedOptions: () => ({ timeZone: 'Africa/Nirobi' }),
        }),
      };
    });
    console.log('Intl', Intl.DateTimeFormat);
  });
```